# open layers 3 - Draw route along road

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a web service which returns a list of coordinates for a route between two points.

```
if (points.length > 0) {

    var routeLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(points, 'XY') })]
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#0091ea', weight: 8 }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#0091ea', width: 4 })
        }),
        name: 'routeLayer'
    });

    map.addLayer(routeLayer);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the web service only returns points when the user needs to make a turn, gets to a roundabout or a junction. This results in straight lines being drawn between points, which does not look right when the roads are curved.

Is there a way to draw the route only along roads, or is the only option (using OL3) to get the web service to return a lot more points to account for curving roads?

OL3 is not essential to the project but it is what we've been using so far so sticking with it would be preferable.

Comment: You must get a lot more points to draw route more accurate.

Comment: you use mmGetCurvePoints() function for draw curve with 2 point or 3 point in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353866/using-cubiccurve-in-openlayers-2